# Capistrano 3.14 cannot get connection to my git during deployment

Tags: git, capistrano

I have done this many times, but now something in the git connection is not working. I create a user into my server and generate a public key for it, added the public key to my git so that Capistrano should be able to pull the code.

But when I try to deploy, I get:

```
00:01 git:check
      01 git ls-remote hth@helixteamhub.cloud:mustalahtisolutions/projects/heater_controller/repositories/git/heater_controller HEAD
      01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
      01
      01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      01 and the repository exists.
```

When I SSH to the server and run `git ls-remote hth@helixteamhub.cloud:mustalahtisolutions/projects/heater_controller/repositories/git/heater_controller HEAD` it works.

WTF Capistrano, what is this? I have read about forward agent solution, but my other projects are deploying fine without it, I should not need it.

How can I make Capistrano to run the commands as the user on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that Capistrano uses forward agent by default, which in my case authenticated against Git with an incorrect identity file. I disabled the forward agent with `set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => false }` and now my deploys are working.